# How do I make my app's service be updated with the server and also be power-efficient

Tags: android, android-service

I have an app which has a service to run in background. The service is pretty useful and kind of need to be updated at anytime and notify the client whenever the server wants to tell the client something. I know that services like steam, whatsapp and any other app are updated at any moment of update in the server (incoming message and etc). My question is theoretically, if I want to make this kind of connection, should I just leave the socket which is connected to the server open at any moment the service is running, so the server can send it messages at any time? will it be power-efficient? 
I'm afraid you won't understand me well, I can provide more info if needed.

edit:
My current service is just using a Timer, so the timer will connect to the server at every few minutes, get the info out of the server and than close the socket and make this whole process again. It works but the `Timer` sometimes misses a loop or two, so it won't be constant. In addition, the user can set the frequency of update (check with server) to any time he wants, and my app provides info that is pretty important and every minute matters, so the user need to get the info from the server as soon as there's a change in the server, but with my `Timer` method can take a few hours until the user gets the info, and it's no longer relevant..

Comment: Have a look at Firebase Cloud Messaging: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: @DamianJäger I will, thank you!
Do I have to change anything with my server in order to do it? I'm using java server

Comment: You will have to tell Firebase to send messages to your app. You can find more info here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message

Comment: @DamianJäger Thank you!

Comment: @DamianJäger Can I make it work with java? My server is using web-scraping and all the libraries I used are in java and I would rather keep it in java

Comment: @EldarAzulay There's a java api for using FCM on the server

Comment: @EldarAzulay sure, you just have to send a normal POST request